# How to display images from a Django CharField?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm building an ecommerce site and there is a selection of images to use as photos for each item. The problem I'm having is displaying the selected photo in the html. The photos arn't uploaded but rather are stored in the static files folder

Here's my model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    PHOTO_CHOICES = [
        ('Fishing Rod', "fishing_rod.png"),
        ('Fishing Net', 'fishing_net.png'),
        ('Tackle Box', 'tackle_box.png'),
        ('Lure', 'lure.png'),
        ('Line', 'line.png'),
        ('Hook', 'hook.png'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=PHOTO_CHOICES, default='Fishing Rod')
```

And here's the html displaying it

```
          {% for item in items %}
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="{% url 'item-detail' item.id %}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'Photos/{{ item.photo }}' %}" alt="" id="photo"></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="{% url 'item-detail' item.id %}">{{ item.name }}</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>${{ item.price }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ item.description }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Here is what it is currently displaying

[image: Here is what it is currently displaying]

And it is supposed to look like this

[image]

Comment: could you provide the current rendered html code for the img tag please

Comment: @jonas Sure, I just updated it

Comment: sorry I meant the html code in your browsers source, so we can see how Django interpretes the src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```html
<a href="{% url 'item-detail' item.id %}">
     <img 
         class="card-img-top"
         src="{% static 'Photos/{{ item.photo }}' %}"
         alt="" id="photo">
</a>
```

calls for the value stored in the database, which is the first value in the choice tuple.

```html
<a href="{% url 'item-detail' item.id %}">
     <img class="card-img-top"
          src="{% static 'Photos/{{ item.get_photo_display }}' %}"
          alt="                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
          id="photo">
</a>
```

renders the 2nd item in the tuple: [the display value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

However, this won't work because we're not in HTML here, but part of a tag, so the easiest way to use it is [`get_static_prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix):

```html
<a href="{% url 'item-detail' item.id %}">
     <img class="card-img-top"
          src="{% get_static_prefix %}Photos/{{ item.get_photo_display }}"
          alt="                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
          id="photo">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the Model so that the file name is the first in the tuple,  however the image is still not displaying.

Comment: You shouldn't have. Look closely at the second HTML line. It's different and it'll work. What you've done by flipping the order is just changing the definition. Things that are already saved, will still have the old value in the database.

Comment: Updated: you can't "render a variable" inside an argument to a template tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply permute element in PHOTO_CHOICES. the first one will be the actual value of the field.

```
   PHOTO_CHOICES = [
        ("fishing_rod.png", 'Fishing Rod'),
        ('fishing_net.png', 'Fishing Net'),
        ('tackle_box.png', 'Tackle Box'),
        ('lure.png', 'Lure'),
        ('line.png', 'Line'),
        ('hook.png', 'Hook'),
    ]
```

if you want to display the second one you can do like:

```
#display_name will be 'Fishing Rod' if item.photo is "fishing_rod.png" etc 
d = dict(item_instance.PHOTO_CHOICES)
display_name = d[item.photo]
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I display that in the html, right now I have it as src="{% static 'Photos/{{ item.photo }}' %}"

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I changed the Model so that the file name is the first in the tuple, however the image is still not displaying

Comment: @David_ is your folder of static files accessible?

Comment: yes, if I put in a hardcoded filename, it displays fine (as shown in the example post), however it doesn't display when the filename src is variable